# how to customize kendogrid filters for text columns in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have to customize kendo-grid filter for text columns but I am using default kendo filter in grid filter.state. Now I have to show following things in the filter:

- Greater than
- Greater than or equal to
- Less than
- Less than or equal to.

but I do not know how to customize. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: See: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/

Comment: Please post your code. Kindly follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve